# Ifc Export Error

Tags: export, error

I get an error while trying to export some meshes into a ifc format from Blender file. I do not know Python yet ;) I would be grateful if anyone could tell me what's wrong in the settings.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons\blenderbim\bim\operator.py", line 107, in execute
    ifc_exporter.export(context.selected_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons\blenderbim\bim\export_ifc.py", line 1376, in export
    self.create_styled_items()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons\blenderbim\bim\export_ifc.py", line 1962, in create_styled_items
    if product['ifc'].Representation:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Representation'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up that the BlenderBIM Add-on has been completely rebuilt and the exporter no longer functions in this manner, so this question is no longer relevant.

By the way, in the future, please feel free to post Python errors like this on https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell issues.